# Prove that the sequence converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{r_n\}$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|< \infty.$ Prove that

$$
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}
$$
converges absolutely for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone provide a useful hint to solve the problem ? I am unable to figure out how does almost every $x$ come into picture. Should I use some lebesgue integral ?

Comment: It seems like some property of $r_n$ should be specified.  For example, what happens if $r_n \geq x$ for one or more terms $n$?

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I forgot to add the modulus. Edited it.

Comment: That does not seem to help.  For example, what if $r_4=x$?

Comment: @Michael that may be fine, this would automatically exclude only countably many points, the question is about *almost every*, I assume for all but measure zero set

Comment: @Michael: As Mirko has pointed out, you can as well remove all $\{r_n\}$ from your desired set of points for which the above property holds, since measure won't change.

Comment: @Mirko : Thanks, that makes the problem more interesting, especially since it is possible to get arbitrarily close to all real numbers with the $r_n$ sequence (say, for example, $r_n$ is a listing of the rationals).

Comment: the $r_n$ could conceivably form a dense set, and $|x-r_n|$ could infinitely often be close to $0$ (for any fixed $x$). For each $x$ one may be able to pick a subsequence with $|x-r_{n_j}|\to0$. Somehow it ought to be relevant that the $a_n$ (or $a_{n_j}$) also go to $0$ and they must go to $0$ faster than the $|x-r_{n_j}|\to0$: At least for almost every $x$. The set of the accumulation points of the $r_n$ may be the whole real line. The $r_n$ may for example be the sequence of all rational numbers, each listed infinitely many times.

Comment: What do you mean with $almost$ please be more specific, this problem is very simple!

Comment: By any chance, are the $r_n$ values assumed to be rational numbers?  I ask because this question has the flavor of known quadratic bounds on approximating irrational numbers with rationals.

Comment: Incorrect answer demoted to a comment: Let $R$ be the set of all $r_n$. Since $R$ is countable, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an open set $U_\varepsilon$ containing $R$ with measure $m(U_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$. It is easily seen (hmm?) that the sum converges absolutely in the complement of $U_\varepsilon$. Let $U=\bigcap_n U_{\frac1n}$. Then $U$ is a $G_\delta$ set of measure $0$ and the sum converges absolutely for each $x$ in the complement of $U$. @Michael interesting idea about approximating irrationals

Comment: @Mirko:  While pillow fighting my son I thought of a way to possibly fix your answer, what if you explictly define the open sets around each $r_n$ to have size that decreases sufficiently fast with $n$?  Got to go now...

Comment: @Michael I guess I should pillow fight more often myself

Comment: just to let you know user @EDUARDO has edited your question adding the extra hypothesis that the derived set of the $r_n$ has measure $0$ in what seems to me an attempt to make their incorrect answer "correct". I just posted a question on meta regarding this. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/editing-the-problem-by-an-answerer-to-make-their-answer-correct

Comment: This problem as stated is wrong, look at the counterexample

Answer (score 4):

For any bounded measurable $A$
$$\int_A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_A\frac {|a_n|}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}<\infty$$
Hence the sum is finite a.s. This can be extended to show a.s. absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nf_n(x)$$
for any locally uniformly integrable $f_n$.

Comment: What does $E$ denote ?

Comment: I don't quite get it, can't connect the dots. I vaguely believe you  need to take limit of the above inequalities as $A$ gets bigger and bigger (so $\sup A\to \mathbb R$) and then the sum may go to $\infty$. Perhaps what you have is right, but is too cryptic for me, or I overlook something related to expectations (or don't see the correct interpretation of what you are doing in terms of suitable probabilities).

Comment: @mirko I've shown that $f<\infty$ a.s. on all bounded $A_l$. Take $A_l=[l,l+1]$ to cover all of $R$.

Comment: I start to get the idea that perhaps it boils down to using that improper integral $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}} dx$ is convergent. I assume your $f_n=\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$. I need to think about the "uniformly" or "locally uniformly" part (first I do not know the definition and need to figure it and make sense of it, may take a while, second once I know what it says I need to convince myself that it works, and that it would work even if the $r_n$ form a dense set).

Comment: The nub of the answer by A.S. is :For bounded measurable $ A$   let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j\leq n}|a_n|/\sqrt {|x-r_n|}$ for $x\in A\setminus (\{0\}\cup \{r_n\}_n).  $  We have $0\leq f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ a.e.  on $A$,  but $\sup_n\int_Af_n(x)dx<\infty.$